# How to iterate over nested dictionaries and lists in django template

Tags: python, html, django

I am working with Google spreadsheets in Django. I have two models

```
class Workbooks(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Sheets(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    workbook=models.ForeignKey(Workbooks)
```

I am in trouble getting this data on the template.I am looking to print list of workbooks and under each workbook i want its corressponding sheets i.e. `Sheets.workbook_id=Workbooks.id`

With this I am able to get the list of workbooks.What I want is to access the sheets model objects for each workbook.

```
{{% for name in workbooks%}}
 {{name}}
{{%endfor%}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this you can use [related object reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/relations/):

```
{% for workbook in workbooks %}
    {{ workbook.name }}<br />
    {% for sheet in workbook.sheets_set.all %}
        - {{ sheet.name }}<br />
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: The problem is with my views.py logic. It is giving me wrong result. Under each workbook name ,i am getting all the sheets from the Sheets model.

Comment: 1. There are no need to pregenerate everything in the view. You can simply do ctx["workbooks"]=Workbooks.objects.all() and that's it :)

Comment: 2. Looks like there are also a bug in your code, you need to put "data = []" below "for workbook in workbooks:", then it should work fine.

Comment: Thnx for correcting the code. Now i am getting correct sheets under each workbook. As you metioned , if i dont  pregenerate  sheets details, will i be able to get it from the template with the help of workbooks object

Comment: hey, thnx mate. I just read Related object reference and understood what you were trying to explain me. It really helped.